# How can I set up an AssaultCube server?

Tags: technical-issues, hosting, ubuntu, assaultcube

Everything I find when Googling it references a file called "bin_unix".  A search of my system indicates I don't have it.  Is there any other way to set a server for AssaultCube?

BTW, I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be because I had an old version.  Apparently the version in the Ubuntu Software Center is not the latest.  I can't figure out how to install it now, but that's a different question.